# Обработать ошибку метода json в fetch

Tags: javascript

Я хочу узнать, что вернул сервер, если при использовании `.json()` возвращается ошибка (SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...), ну или другие (если это возможно).

```js
fetch('http://test')
.catch(err => console.log('fetch err:', err))
.then(res => res.json())
.catch(err => console.log('json err:', err)) // данный catch должен вернуть, что пришло в ответе
.then(res => console.log('res', res))
.catch(err => console.log('global err:', err))
```

А так же, как отменить все последующие catch, если до него уже сработал другой?

Comment: просто так нельзя отменить все следующие .then и .catch